# How to add ccavenue donate button in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, payment-gateway, ccavenue, donations

I am new to payment gateways integration, I want one donate button which will be processed by ccavenue, user will need to type the donation amount, I want the overview of How I'll integrate it? what plugin, API, Extension, Theme, Custom code change I'll need to do.

I tried to contact ccavenue team but they are not available, Their servers are down. I tried to watch youtube videos, but all videos are about paypal donation button integration, But my client is demanding only for ccavenue donate button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution, I used [WooCommerce CCAvenue gateway](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ccavenue-payment-gateway-woocommerce/) for gateway integration and, [WooCommerce Quick Donation](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-quick-donation/) for donation input by user.